# Doxygen doesn't show inlince sources with c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, documentation, doxygen

I'm having some troubles with Doxygen and c++ templates. With this code (without templates), Doxygen will generate fine inline sources:

```c++
/** \file node.h
  * \version 1.0
  * \date 24/04/2015
  * \author Daniel Ramos Acosta
  * \title Clase plantilla nodo
  * \brief Contiene la definición e implementación de la clase node
  * \code
  * //Código de ejemplo
  *
  * template<class T>
  * class listNode : public dra::node<T>{
  * private:
  *     listNode* next_;
  *     listNode* prev_;
  * public:
  *     //....
  * };
  *
  * \endcode
*/

#ifndef NODE
#define NODE


namespace dra{
    class node;
}

class dra::node{
    /*!
     * \class dra::node<T>
     * \brief Esta clase representa un nodo genérico
     * \details
     * Esta clase representa a un nodo genérico de un grafo. para usarlo, uno hereda
     * de esta clase, y añade la cantidad de enlaces que desee. Puede servir para
     * una lista enlazada, un árbol binario, o simplemente un grafo.
     */
private:
    int data_;
public:
    /*! \name Constructores y destructor*/
    ///@{
    /*!
     * \brief Este es el constructor por defecto del nodo.
     */
    node(void);

    /*!
     * \brief Este es el constructor al que se le pasa un dato a almacenar
     * \param data Es el dato que se le pasa al consutructor del nodo
     */
    node(const T data);

    /*!
     * \brief Este es el destructor, no hace nada especial.
     */
    ~node(void);
    ///@}

    /*! \name Métodos de acceso al dato*/
    ///@{
    /*!
     * \brief Este metodo devuelve el dato para poder modificarlo
     * \return Devuelve una referencia al dato del nodo, por lo que se puede modificar.
     */
    T& data(void);

    /*!
     * \brief Este metodo devuelve el dato para poder leerlo
     * \return Devuelve una copia del dato, por lo tanto no se edita el dato del nodo
     */
    T data(void) const;
    ///@}
};

dra::node::node(void)
{}

dra::node::node(const int data):
    data_(data)
{}

dra::node::~node(void)
{}

T& dra::node::data(void)
{
    return data_;
}

T dra::node::data(void) const
{
    return data_;
    //Cosas complejas
}

#endif // NODE
```

But with this other code with templates, it won't:

```c++
/** \file node.h
  * \version 1.0
  * \date 24/04/2015
  * \author Daniel Ramos Acosta
  * \title Clase plantilla nodo
  * \brief Contiene la definición e implementación de la clase node
  * \code
  * //Código de ejemplo
  *
  * template<class T>
  * class listNode : public dra::node<T>{
  * private:
  *     listNode* next_;
  *     listNode* prev_;
  * public:
  *     //....
  * };
  *
  * \endcode
*/

#ifndef NODE
#define NODE

namespace dra{
    template<class T> class node;
}


template<class T>
class dra::node{
    /*!
     * \class dra::node<T>
     * \brief Esta clase representa un nodo genérico
     * \details
     * Esta clase representa a un nodo genérico de un grafo. para usarlo, uno hereda
     * de esta clase, y añade la cantidad de enlaces que desee. Puede servir para
     * una lista enlazada, un árbol binario, o simplemente un grafo.
     */
private:
    T data_;
public:
    /*! \name Constructores y destructor*/
    ///@{
    /*!
     * \brief Este es el constructor por defecto del nodo.
     */
    node(void);

    /*!
     * \brief Este es el constructor al que se le pasa un dato a almacenar
     * \param data Es el dato que se le pasa al consutructor del nodo
     */
    node(const T data);

    /*!
     * \brief Este es el destructor, no hace nada especial.
     */
    ~node(void);
    ///@}

    /*! \name Métodos de acceso al dato*/
    ///@{
    /*!
     * \brief Este metodo devuelve el dato para poder modificarlo
     * \return Devuelve una referencia al dato del nodo, por lo que se puede modificar.
     */
    T& data(void);

    /*!
     * \brief Este metodo devuelve el dato para poder leerlo
     * \return Devuelve una copia del dato, por lo tanto no se edita el dato del nodo
     */
    T data(void) const;
    ///@}
};

template<class T>
dra::node<T>::node(void)
{}

template<class T>
dra::node<T>::node(const T data):
    data_(data)
{}

template<class T>
dra::node<T>::~node(void)
{}

template<class T>
T& dra::node<T>::data(void)
{
    return data_;
}

template<class T>
T dra::node<T>::data(void) const
{
    return data_;
}


#endif // NODE
```

Do you know why? I can't get it to work. The only clue I have are that if I remove the templates, I get the inline sources to work... I have all the sources and Doxygen config file in [github](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/university/tree/master/AEDA/Pr%C3%A1cticas/6) if you want to clone or something.

Answer (score 0):

I included all the methods in the namespace and now works. I think I'm going to leave it like this. Still don't know why doesn't work with the declaration of the namespace.

```c++
/** \file node.h
  * \version 1.0
  * \date 24/04/2015
  * \author Daniel Ramos Acosta
  * \title Clase plantilla nodo
  * \brief Contiene la definición e implementación de la clase node
  * \code
  * //Código de ejemplo
  *
  * template<class T>
  * class listNode : public dra::node<T>{
  * private:
  *     listNode* next_;
  *     listNode* prev_;
  * public:
  *     //....
  * };
  *
  * \endcode
*/

#ifndef NODE
#define NODE

namespace dra{

template<class T>
class node{
    /*!
     * \class node<T>
     * \brief Esta clase representa un nodo genérico
     * \details
     * Esta clase representa a un nodo genérico de un grafo. para usarlo, uno hereda
     * de esta clase, y añade la cantidad de enlaces que desee. Puede servir para
     * una lista enlazada, un árbol binario, o simplemente un grafo.
     */
private:
    T data_;
public:
    /*! \name Constructores y destructor*/
    ///@{
    /*!
     * \brief Este es el constructor por defecto del nodo.
     */
    node(void);

    /*!
     * \brief Este es el constructor al que se le pasa un dato a almacenar
     * \param data Es el dato que se le pasa al consutructor del nodo
     */
    node(const T data);

    /*!
     * \brief Este es el destructor, no hace nada especial.
     */
    ~node(void);
    ///@}

    /*! \name Métodos de acceso al dato*/
    ///@{
    /*!
     * \brief Este metodo devuelve el dato para poder modificarlo
     * \return Devuelve una referencia al dato del nodo, por lo que se puede modificar.
     */
    T& data(void);

    /*!
     * \brief Este metodo devuelve el dato para poder leerlo
     * \return Devuelve una copia del dato, por lo tanto no se edita el dato del nodo
     */
    T data(void) const;
    ///@}
};

template<class T>
node<T>::node(void)
{}

template<class T>
node<T>::node(const T data):
    data_(data)
{}

template<class T>
node<T>::~node(void)
{}

template<class T>
T& node<T>::data(void)
{
    return data_;
}

template<class T>
T node<T>::data(void) const
{
    return data_;
}

}

#endif // NODE
```